# Which usage is correct? “cover by somebody” or “covered by somebody”

Tags: word-choice

Most people on the Internet use “cover by somebody".  Is it correct?

Comment: You mean song covers?

Comment: Please could you add some context to your question? Maybe an example of where you have seen this?

Comment: Before we can help you express something, we have to understand what it is that you want to express. Please give us more information.

Comment: You can [edit] you post to address users' concerns. Please see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 2):

"Cover" as a verb: When you "cover" a song you sing it after someone else already did their version of it.

"Cover" as a noun: Another version of a song that was already famous before when another artist sang it.

So, "cover"? or "covered"? ...  It could be either.

The song could be "**covered** by Somebody" (to cover = verb).

Or the song could be "a **cover** by Somebody" (a cover = noun).